# Unsupported operand types functions.php

Tags: php

I get an error (several) in my wordpress

```
[12-Feb-2024 11:16:42 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in /mnt/web009/d0/04/56730904/htdocs/STRATO-apps/wordpress_03/app/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/functions.php:206
```

(this is the 206 line:)

```
'group_price' => $standar_price * (100 - $pod->field('group_price')) / 100, //6-19
```

Thanks

The website works ok in the main language, but in the second language there are link that result in  "critical error" a page.
Example: http://test2.tarifaexperience.com/events/1-day-trip-to-tanger-with-dni/?lang=en

This is the fragment, and only the line group_price get an error. I have reviewed the syntax and it is the same as other lines.

```
$price_array = array(
        'adults' => $standar_price,
       'kid_4_14' => $kids_4_14_price,
       'kid_3_12' => $kids_3_12_price,
       'babies_0_3' => $baby_0_3_price,
       'babies_0_2' => $baby_0_2_price,
       'group_price_four_persons' => $standar_price * (100 - $pod->field('group_price_fourpersons')) / 100, //4-10
       'group_price_three_persons' => $standar_price * (100 - $pod->field('group_price_threepersons')) / 100,
       'group_price_two_persons' => $standar_price * (100 - $pod->field('group_price_twopersons')) / 100,
       'group_price' => $standar_price * (100 - $pod->field('group_price')) / 100, //6-19
       'group_kids_price' => $kids_4_14_price * (100 - $pod->field('group_price')) / 100,
       'group_kids_price_four_persons' => $kids_3_12_price * (100 - $pod->field('group_kid_price_fourpersons')) / 100,
       'group_kids_price_three_persons' => $kids_3_12_price * (100 - $pod->field('group_kid_price_threepersons')) / 100,
       'group_kids_price_two_persons' => $kids_3_12_price * (100 - $pod->field('group_kid_price_twopersons')) / 100,
       'big_family' => $standar_price * (100 - $pod->field('big_family')) / 100,
       'student' => $standar_price * (100 - $pod->field('student')) / 100,
       'unemployed' => $standar_price * (100 - $pod->field('unemployed')) / 100,
       'disabled_person' => $standar_price * (100 - $pod->field('disabled')) / 100,
       'retired' => $standar_price * (100 - $pod->field('retired')) / 100,
       'not_suitable_for_children' => $pod->field('not_suitable_for_children'),
       'category' => get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'event_type')[0]->slug,
       'supplements' => $name_price,
       'locale' => get_locale(),
       'webba_id' => $pod->field('webba_id'), 

   );
```

Comment: Is it `'group_price' => $standar_price * (100 - intval($pod->field('group_price')) / 100;`?

Comment: Or perhaps a spelling mistake: `$standar_price` could be: `$standard_price`? We would need to see the rest of the code, or know the values of the variables, to get any idea.

Comment: One or both of those variables is a string that cannot be reasonably converted to a number. Also the error message you've quoted does not appear to be properly formatted and should be telling you exactly what the issue is: https://3v4l.org/THYAE

Comment: @deEr. Don't do that. It will just mask the error. https://3v4l.org/sESBU#v8.3.2

Comment: Thanks, can I send you the function.php code?

Comment: Questions and answers on Stack Overflow are meant to be public, not private. If you've got something to add to your question [you can edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77983477/edit). Also note that nobody has reacted to your second question, that's because you should, preferably, focus on one question and give all the information you have about that.

Comment: This is the fragment, and only the 8ª line has an error. I have reviewed the syntax and it is the same as other lines

Comment: It's a fatal error, so all the other lines that follow, that look the same, aren't executed. The code below the error is therefore not really relevant, so all told, you added six lines of code, and not the lines we needed to understand your problem. We still don't have the value of the variables you use in the 8ª line.